# In a SQL loop how to I amend to a sub-array?

Tags: php, json

I am trying to add data in from SQL loop into a specific section of an array, however it does't seem to keep the array format when I do a json encode.

I create the array:

```
$array['type'] = 'update';
$array['tags']['data'] = array(array('name' => "Tag", 'tags' => array()));
```

Then in my sql loop in the while:

```
$array['tags']['data']['tags'][] = array('a' => "$row[a]", 'b' => "$row[b]");
```

after this loop, json encode:

```
json_encode($array);
```

In the output, the "tags" has the rows added under data, and the one I setup for the array is now under tags:data:0:tags , and it has not populated this.

Also `data` has gone from `[ ]` to `{ }`, and I need it to be `[{ }]`. If I take out the loop, the data section is with  `[ { } ]` as expected.

Hope that makes sense! if not can expand more.

Many thanks

Comment: _Side note:_ You don't need to quote variables to use them. Instead of `"$row[a]"`, just do: `$row['a']`

Comment: Please show us the expected and your current output.

Comment: `Also data has gone from [ ] to { }`  In JSON, PHP associative arrays (`[key=>value]`) become objects in the JSON `{key:value}` so if you have string keys at that level then you need to wrap it in an additional array `php [[key=>value]]` =  `json [{key:value}]` or remove the string keys `php [0=>value] or [value]` = `json [value]`.  Without seeing it, it's hard to visualize exactly what you have and therefor hard to recommend one way over the other.

Comment: hi all, thanks for the quick replies.

Comment: what I am getting:

{
    "type": "update",
    "tags": {
        "data": {
            "0": {
                "name": "Tag",
                "tags": []
            },
            "tags": [
                {
                    "a": "tag1",
                    "b": "desc1"
                },
                {
                    "a": "tag2",
                    "b": "desc2"

                }
            ]
        }
    }
}

Comment: what I am after:

{
    "type": "update",
    "tags": {
        "data": [
 {
                "name": "Tag",
                "tags": [
                {
                    "a": "tag1",
                    "b": "desc1"
                },
                {
                    "a": "tag2",
                    "b": "desc2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
}

Comment: hi, has been resolved below. missed that [0] in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra array between `data` and `tags`

```
$array['tags']['data'] = array(array('name' => "Tag", 'tags' => array()));
print_r($array);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [tags] => Array
        (
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Tag
                            [tags] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Then you try to access (for assignment)

```
$array['tags']['data']['tags'][] = array('a' => "$row[a]", 'b' => "$row[b]");
```

Which based on your `$array` should actually be

```
$array['tags']['data'][0]['tags'][]
```

Or something like that...

Without more to actually go on that's the best I can do, this really doesn't rate a answer, but there was no way to illustrate an array with that much nesting within a comment.

What you'll wind up with is something like this:

```
Array
(
    [tags] => Array
        (
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Tag
                            [tags] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        ),
                    [tags] => Array
                       (
                           [0] => Array
                           (
                              a => "$row[a]",
                              b => "$row[b]"
                           )
                          [1] => Array(...)
                       )

                )

        )

)
```

Which because of the mixed keys `['data' => [0 => ['name'=>'Tag',...], 'tags' => [...]]`  Will give you a JSON object at that location `{data : {0:{name:"Tag",...},tags:[]}}`

P.S  this really annoys me `"$row[a]"` - I don't know why but it does ... lol

Comment: Sure, it's pretty easy to spot if you print the $array variable out.